# When building a dissector: How to declare an error?

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm building a dissector and I would like to know if it is possible to explicitly declare about errors. for example: If something's length should be 0, but it doesn't, then I want to say "error, something is wrong"

Thanks ahead.

Thanks to "SidR", You should take the following line, and do variations on him.
(remember to include `epan/expert.h` )

```
expert_add_info_format(pinfo, acp_data_tree, PI_MALFORMED, PI_WARN, "Length > 0");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out on [expert infos.](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvExpert.html)

I think the necessary functions are on "epan/expert.h". You can look at "epan/dissector/packet-tcp.c" for an example implementation.